# Replace a continuous probability distribution with a discrete one

Tags: probability-distributions, discrete-mathematics, entropy

Say one wants to fit a curve $f(x)$ to a set of noisy data points $(x_i, y_i)$. If the error for each point $y_i$ is assumed to be normally distributed with variance $\sigma_i^2$, one wants to find the curve that minimizes the sum of weighted error, which is commonly given by:
$$\text{Weighted Error}=\sum_i\left(\frac{y_i-f(x)}{\sigma_i}\right)^2$$
I'm looking for the equivalent of this expression for the discrete case, i.e. when instead of a normal distribution, the probability that $f(x_i)$ passes through any given $y$ is defined using a discrete probability distribution of the form:
$$P(f(x_i)=y)=\sum_j A_j \delta(y,y_j)$$
**My questions for today:**

1. I assume the corresponding quantity for the weighted error, in analogy with the normal distribution, is given by the function: $$G=-\log P(f(x))$$ Is this assumption correct?
2. How would one find the derivative of this quantity in the discrete case? i.e finding the value of:
   $$\frac{dG} {dx}=\frac{-d \log P(f(x))} {dx}$$
3. In general, why the sum of weighted errors usually minimized instead of the expected value, a.k.a the [information entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29)?

Any help gladly appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand the first sentence. "a given normal" : this includes the parameters? If so, we minimizing with respect to what? Why is that error "weighted"? Would you explain better or give some reference?

Comment: @leonbloy - Thank you for your instructive comment - I tried to revise the question as to make the context clearer. Please let me know if the question is still unclear.

Comment: A little clearer, the first formula, not enough the rest. "If the error is normal... one wants to ... minimize ... (formula)" Why? If you don't give some criterion, we don't know how to generalize. Eg, a possible reason is that you are maximizing the likelihood. I further don't understand the question, and what derivative you are speaking of (with respect to what? If f(x) is discrete, you can't derive that!). Again, if you'd give some reference or context, it could be easir to understand

Comment: @nbubis Did you find a solution to this problem. I am interested if there exist a general method to convert a continuous probability distribution with a discrete one? Would you please let me know?